# I need to split an url in php

Tags: php, split, http-referer

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $sitio = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

I need to split $sitio so i have "example" instead of "http://example.com/subfolder" or "http://www.example.com/subfolder"!

Comment: google "split url php" (this is a very basic question, that can easily be answered by google (or even better, searching on php.net))

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`parse_url`**](https://www.php.net/parse_url).

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $sitio = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])['host'];
}
```